# Protractor: Looking for a text to show when I click on an object

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Im working with protactor 5.1.1 and chromedriver_2.27.
When clicking on schedule button I want to wait until the message of "Scheduling complete" shows up . I have tried the following code (and the code that is commented as well) with no success. Every time protractor will continue regardless. Any ideas?

[image][image]

```
that.serviceFilter.sendKeys(serviceName).then(function() {
  utilsObj.doActionWithWait(that.serviceRowInServiceList, function() {
    utilsObj.doActionWithWait(that.pickFilteredService, function() {
      that.pickFilteredService.click().then(function() {
        that.selectAllBtn.click().then(function() {
          that.actionBtn.click().then(function() {
            that.scheduleBtn.click()

            // //EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
            // var aaa = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='SchedulingInProgress']"));
            // browser.wait(function () {
            //   return EC.visibilityOf(aaa).call().then(function (present) {
            //     console.log('\n' + 'looking for element....')
            //     if (present) {
            //       console.log('\n' + 'element not found!')
            //       return true;
            //     } else {
            //       console.log('\n' + 'element found!!')
            //       return false;
            //     }
            //   });
            // }, 50000);

          });
          browser.wait(function() {
            return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath("//*[@id='SchedulingInProgress']"))
          })
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates you are using - `isElementPresent()` incorrectly. Its a function on ElementFinder Object and not on driver.

InCorrect Usage - `browser.driver.isElementPresent()`

Correct Usage - `browser.driver.FindElement().isElementPresent()`

More details [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent). If your goal here is to wait till a particular element shows up .. You are on the right path - Use [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) and they fit into `browser.wait` very nicely. You can do something like this - `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 5000); //wait for an element to become` clickable

Look [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) on its usage

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got the solution!

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.css("#SchedulingInProgress > div:nth-child(2) > div"));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), 50000);
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual('Scheduled 1 out of 1');
```